# How can we assign length for the regex Code in WPF XAML Code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress-wpf

how can we input the length in the `regex` code for the following Code. 
now we can insert more than 15 `digits` if i use `regex` as `mask`

```
 <dxe:ButtonEdit x:Name="txtEdtMobile" Width="Auto"  MaxLength="15" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="7" Margin="2,2,2,2" ValidateOnTextInput="True"  ToolTip="SearchCountryCode" Mask="[+ 0-9]+" MaskType="RegEx" />
```

Comment: can you use {0,15} at the end of you regex?

Comment: Mask="[+ 0-9]+{0,15}"- here it is not working

Comment: `dxe:` means that the control is a custom one. Was it made by you? Or is it from a library?

Comment: it is devExpress control

Answer (score -1):

see the below lines, may be this would help you. In place of 256 you can add your digits like you want to add.

^(?!^.{256})([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)